# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 599

Tags: python, ms-word

my problem is, that I want to extract some lines from a word document.
Therefor I have tried a few methods to do so and that's my current program:

```
a = open("Z:/xyz/xyz/xyz/test.docx","r")
b = a.readlines()
a.close()

count = 0
for line in b:
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        print(line)
```

I always get the UnicodeDecodeError which I declined as my header for this post.
Even if I try "encoding="utf-8", I get another Error called "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 14"
Or with "encoding='Latin-1'" some weird figures as output.

Comment: use python-docx to read a .docx file link: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in binary mode using `'b'`.

```
with open("D:/xyz/xyz.docx",'rb') as f:
    b = f.readline()

count = 0
for line in b:
    count += 1
    if count == 3:
        print(line)
```

Comment: thx for helping, but I already solved the problem now, with converting the file from .docx to .txt and then everything works